# How to use Sessions in asp.net with crystal reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am new to .net and C# and my asp crystal report will not print or export. I have read that you have to use sessions to do this. Can anyone give me any tips for this? I have a basic web page setup that lets you see our report and input a parameter. That is working fine. Whenever I try to print or export my page starts to do something then stops and I get nothing. Any suggestions?here is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection CN;
     String MyConnectionString = null;
     MyConnectionString =  "data source=srv;initial catalog=db;user id=reports;password=";
     CN = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
     CN.Open();
     string SQL = null;
     SQL =  "SELECT oeordhdr_sql.ord_no,  oeordlin_sql.line_seq_no, oeordlin_sql.qty_to_ship, oeordlin_sql.cus_item_no, imitmidx_sql.upc_cd, imitmidx_sql.item_desc_1, oelincmt_sql.cmt, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_name, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_addr_1, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_addr_2, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_addr_3, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_addr_4,sycdefil_sql.cd_type, sycdefil_sql.code_desc FROM(((oeordhdr_sql   oeordhdr_sql  INNER JOIN  oeordlin_sql   oeordlin_sql  ON( oeordhdr_sql.ord_type  =  oeordlin_sql.ord_type ) AND( oeordhdr_sql.ord_no  =  oeordlin_sql.ord_no )) LEFT OUTER JOIN  oelincmt_sql   oelincmt_sql  ON  oeordhdr_sql.ord_no  =  oelincmt_sql.ord_no ) LEFT OUTER JOIN  sycdefil_sql   sycdefil_sql  ON  oeordhdr_sql.ship_via_cd  =  sycdefil_sql.sy_code ) INNER JOIN  imitmidx_sql   imitmidx_sql  ON  oeordlin_sql.item_no  =  imitmidx_sql.item_no WHERE sycdefil_sql.cd_type  = 'V' AND  oeordhdr_sql.ord_no  = ' {?Ord_no}' ORDER BY  oeordhdr_sql.ord_no";

     SqlDataAdapter myDa = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, CN);
     CN.Close();
     DataSet DS = new DataSet();
     myDa.Fill(DS, "DataTable1");
     ReportDocument myRPT = new ReportDocument();
     myRPT.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt"));
     myRPT.SetDataSource(DS);
     CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myRPT;
}
```

Comment: you need to be more specific in regards to what's going on in the code you posted. for example does the code that you posted execute and fill the DataSet Properly..? also in order to get at the underlying datatable of `DS` you should set the `myRPRT.SetDataSource(DS.Tables[0]);`

Comment: The code works, it return the data based on the parameter that is input, but when I press the print button or export, it does nothing.

Comment: check this posting for threads and suggestions this could be a JavaScript Issue you are experiencing http://forums.asp.net/t/992330.aspx?Crystal+Report+Viewer+Export+Print+buttons+are+not+working+in+VS+2005

Answer (score 0):

It turns out all that I needed to do was to add an if(!Page.IsPostback)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
     SqlConnection CN;
     String MyConnectionString = null;
     MyConnectionString =  "data source=srv;initial catalog=db;user id=reports;password=";
     CN = new SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
     CN.Open();
     string SQL = null;
     SQL =  "SELECT oeordhdr_sql.ord_no,  oeordlin_sql.line_seq_no, oeordlin_sql.qty_to_ship, oeordlin_sql.cus_item_no, imitmidx_sql.upc_cd, imitmidx_sql.item_desc_1, oelincmt_sql.cmt, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_name, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_addr_1, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_addr_2, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_addr_3, oeordhdr_sql.ship_to_addr_4,sycdefil_sql.cd_type, sycdefil_sql.code_desc FROM(((oeordhdr_sql   oeordhdr_sql  INNER JOIN  oeordlin_sql   oeordlin_sql  ON( oeordhdr_sql.ord_type  =  oeordlin_sql.ord_type ) AND( oeordhdr_sql.ord_no  =  oeordlin_sql.ord_no )) LEFT OUTER JOIN  oelincmt_sql   oelincmt_sql  ON  oeordhdr_sql.ord_no  =  oelincmt_sql.ord_no ) LEFT OUTER JOIN  sycdefil_sql   sycdefil_sql  ON  oeordhdr_sql.ship_via_cd  =  sycdefil_sql.sy_code ) INNER JOIN  imitmidx_sql   imitmidx_sql  ON  oeordlin_sql.item_no  =  imitmidx_sql.item_no WHERE sycdefil_sql.cd_type  = 'V' AND  oeordhdr_sql.ord_no  = ' {?Ord_no}' ORDER BY  oeordhdr_sql.ord_no";

     SqlDataAdapter myDa = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, CN);
     CN.Close();
     DataSet DS = new DataSet();
     myDa.Fill(DS, "DataTable1");
     ReportDocument myRPT = new ReportDocument();
     myRPT.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CrystalReport.rpt"));
     myRPT.SetDataSource(DS);
     CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myRPT;
}
}
```